# Creating a folder named "CON" in Windows

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to rename a folder or a file as ‘con’](https://superuser.com/questions/86999/unable-to-rename-a-folder-or-a-file-as-con)

I tried crating a folder with the name **CON** in Windows, but I couldn't crate it in any of the hard drives.

What could be the reason? Is it possible to create such a folder?

Answer (score 10):

as previously stated. it's a reserved word from back in MS-DOS, for the CONsole device (as far as i can remember). but, you can force windows/dos to create the folder for you. for devices, it uses the format `\\.\[RESERVED_WORD]` to access the "file" (these devices used files for communication). to force windows to create your folder, instead of doing `mkdir [RESERVED_WORD]`, do the following:

```
mkdir \\.\[absolute path to folder of choice, including drive letter]\[RESERVED_WORD]
```

for example, to create CON folder on my desktop,

```
mkdir \\.\C:\Users\me\Desktop\CON
```

to delete the folder, you have to reference it the same way, or else it won't work.

```
rmdir \\.\C:\Users\me\Desktop\CON
```

my advice though is to just use a different name. it would be very difficult to always refer to it via its absolute path, especially if you are developing an app you plan on deploying.

Answer (score 9):

It's a reserved name from the old MS-DOS days.  You couldn't create filenames the same as MS-DOS driver names, and this still stands in today's versions of Windows.  See the following Microsoft article for the list of other reserved names.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/74496/en-us

Comment: "You couldn't create" – and you likely shouldn't. In my school days, when I  learnt about those special file names, I tried to input those into various programs certainly not expecting them as user input. Interesting for me, some actually disallow at least those reserved named that I used. Other results were: DO NOT DO THAT! For example, Dungeon Keeper II locks up when fed `CON` as the save name. So depending on how the file/folder is gonna be used, it may have same ill effects.

Comment: Not **requiring** the colon on the end... `CON:` ...seemed like such a good idea at the time.  20/20 hindsight.

Answer (score 2):

CON is a reserved name (short for console).  Specifying 'con' as a filename for a command line tool will often output data to the screen (if it doesn't just fail, like a lot of .Net apps do).  There are a few other reserved names, like AUX for example.