# Which characters are invalid for an MS-DOS filename?

Tags: filenames, ms-dos, data-validation

I'm writing a filename I/O procedure in x86-16 assembly language. It takes eight characters (I don't need to support long filenames) from the keyboard and prints them to an on-screen text input field.

At the moment I'm allowing numbers, upper/lower-case letters, underscores, and hyphens.

I'd like to allow all legal symbols, but I can't find an official list of banned characters. Common sense tells me that slashes are illegal, but if I had to guess, I would say that the plus character is legal. (edit: It's not!)

I'm already ignoring the period character since my code automatically handles appending the period and file extension.

Comment: You might also find [retrocomputing.se] useful.

Comment: Try to create a folder in Windows and put a '?' in the name. A tooltip tells you which characters are forbidden. This gives you a start :)...

Comment: @Mixxiphoid that won't work because the set of allowed characters in Windows are much larger. For example `+,;[]`, space and `a-z` are allowed in Windows but not DOS. Explorer gives me the error "A file name can't contain any of the following characters `\ / : * ? " < > |` which is just a subset of the banned characters in DOS

Comment: @phuclv that is why I said 'This gives you a start' and also why this is a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Why all MS-DOS symbols? Why not also consider other older OS rules?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A concise summary can be found [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename#Directory_table):

> Legal characters for DOS filenames include the following:
>
> - Upper case letters `A`–`Z`
> - Numbers `0`–`9`
> - Space (though trailing spaces in either the base name or the extension are considered to be padding and not a part of the filename, also filenames with spaces in them must be enclosed in quotes to be used on a DOS command line, and if the DOS command is built programmatically, the filename must be enclosed in quadruple quotes when viewed as a variable within the program building the DOS command.)
> - `` ! # $ % & ' ( ) - @ ^ _ ` { } ~ ``
> - Values 128–255 (though if NLS services are active in DOS, some characters interpreted as lowercase are invalid and unavailable)
>
> This excludes the following ASCII characters:
>
> - `" * + , / : ; < = > ? \ [ ] |` [9]
> - Windows/MS-DOS has no shell escape character
> - `.` (U+002E . full stop) within name and extension fields, except in . and .. entries (see below)
> - Lower case letters `a`–`z` (stored as A–Z on FAT12/FAT16)
> - Control characters 0–31
> - Value 127 (DEL)[dubious – discuss]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename#Directory_table

And here's what MS-DOS 6 user guide officially said

> ## Naming Files and Directories
>
> Every file and directory, except for the root directory on each drive, must have a name. The following list summarizes the rules for naming files and directories. File and directory names:
>
> - Can be up to eight characters long. In addition, you can include an extension up to three characters long.
> - Are not case-sensitive. It does not matter whether you use uppercase or lowercase letters when you type them.
> - Can contain only the letters A through Z, the numbers 0 through 9, and the following special characters: underscore (`_`), caret (`^`), dollar sign (`$`), tilde (`~`), exclamation point (`!`), number sign (`#`), percent sign (`%`), ampersand (`&`), hyphen (`-`), braces (`{}`), at sign (`@`), single quotation mark (`` ` ``), apostrophe (`'`), and parentheses `()`. No other special characters are acceptable.
> - Cannot contain spaces, commas, backslashes, or periods (except the period that separates the name from the extension).
> - Cannot be identical to the name of another file or subdirectory in the same directory.

- [Concise User’s Guide - Microsoft® MS-DOS® 6](https://archive.org/details/microsoft-ms-dos-6/page/n25)
- [Concise User’s Guide - Microsoft® MS-DOS® 6 - alternate link](https://the-eye.eu/public/Site-Dumps/RemoteCPU_Archive/Microsoft%20MS-DOS%206%20-%20User%27s%20Guide.pdf)

This is from PC-DOS 7:

> The name you assign to a file must meet the following criteria:
>
> - It can contain no more than eight characters.
> - It can consist of the letters A through Z, the numbers 0 through 9, and the following special characters:
>
>   ```
>   _ underscore            ^  caret
>   $ dollar sign           ~  tilde
>   ! exclamation point     #  number sign
>   % percent sign          &  ampersand
>   - hyphen                {} braces
>   @ at sign               `  single quote
>   ' apostrophe            () parentheses
>   ```
>
> Note: No other special characters are acceptable.
>
> - The name cannot contain spaces, commas, backslashes, or periods (except the period that separates the name from the extension).
> - The name cannot be one of the following reserved file names: CLOCK$, CON, AUX, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, NUL, and PRN.
> - It cannot be the same name as another file within the directory.

[User's Guide - PC DOS 7](http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/ibm/pc/dos/83G9260_IBM_PC_DOS_7.0_Users_Guide_Jan95.pdf)

> The first byte of a name must not be 0x20 (space). Short names or extensions are padded with spaces. Special ASCII characters 0x22 (`"`), 0x2a (`*`), 0x2b (`+`), 0x2c (`,`), 0x2e (`.`), 0x2f (`/`), 0x3a (`:`), 0x3b (`;`), 0x3c (`<`), 0x3d (`=`), 0x3e (`>`), 0x3f (`?`), 0x5b (`[`), 0x5c (`\`), 0x5d (`]`), 0x7c (`|`) are not allowed.

[The FAT filesystem](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/fs/fat/fat-1.html#ss1.4)

If you're also interested in MS-DOS 5.0 then [here it is](https://archive.org/details/microsoft-ms-dos-5/page/n97).

Comment: It might be worth noting that even though they only contain valid characters the special filenames `CON`, `PRN`, `AUX`, `NUL`, `COM1`, `COM2`, `COM3`, `COM4`, `COM5`, `COM6`, `COM7`, `COM8`, `COM9`, `LPT1`, `LPT2`, `LPT3`, `LPT4`, `LPT5`, `LPT6`, `LPT7`, `LPT8`, and `LPT9` are also not permitted (see [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/naming-a-file))

Comment: @ThomasSchremser "Do not use", "Avoid" and "Not recommended" is not the same as "not permitted".

Comment: @RobIII Yes but they linked to "Windows > Desktop" documentation, not to "MS-DOS" documentation. The [wiki for DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS#Reserved_device_names) says, "There are reserved device names in DOS that cannot be used as filenames regardless of extension as they are occupied by built-in character devices". In other words, not permitted in DOS and some versions of Windows, and not recommended in other Windows versions.

Comment: It's interesting that the ` is referred to as a single quote. I've always heard it called a backtick, and the ' (what they call (not incorrectly) an apostrophe) as a single quote.

Comment: @ale10ander yeah that surprised me to. I've always hated that many people use it for the apostrophe (like in I\`m) or the begin part of the quote. For example GNU documentations always write `like this' which is very ugly and less readable to me

Comment: Interestingly, even in Windows 7 (and possibly beyond?) an attempt to create a folder named `CON` will fail. The special filenames have been around a looong time.

Comment: @smitelli it's just for backward compatibility when running commands in the console. You can create files/folders with those names on Windows easily without problem. [Creating a folder named "CON" in Windows](https://superuser.com/q/129141/241386),

Answer (score 14):

Strictly speaking, as an MS/PC/DR-DOS applications programmer you are supposed to ask the operating system for this information.  INT 0x21 with AX=0x6505 returns a pointer to the so-called `FCHAR` NLS table for your country and code page.  This table lists a range of characters and a further set of characters that terminate filenames.

In theory it varies by country and code page.  But the fact that it was not formally carried over into the OS/2 Control Program API and the fact that [FreeDOS has 1 table across all codepages and countries](https://github.com/FDOS/country/blob/master/country.asm#L3680) show that it is largely invariant in practice.

## Further reading

- http://ctyme.com/intr/rb-3163.htm
- http://ctyme.com/intr/rb-3163.htm#Table1754

Answer (score 11):

I found this in a manual for MS-DOS 3.3. I'm running 6.22, but it probably still applies. I was wrong about '+' being allowed.

[image]

Comment: A manual from back-in-the-day is more reliable than Wikipedia

Comment: @Stewart what's important are the quotes on Wikipedia, not Wikipedia itself. If in doubt just check the footnotes and references in the article \@Mylifeisabug I've just added the MS-DOS 6 manual

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to validate the filename, you may want to use [`INT 21H/AH=60H (TRUENAME - CANONICALIZE FILENAME OR PATH)`](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-3137.htm) after ensuring that the passed filename doesn't have a colon or backslash (those may be treated as drive letters and directories): the function takes your proposed filename and tries to canonicalize it by uppercasing the letters and checking for invalid characters (it also adds a drive letter/server name and path.)

In pseudocode:

```
If !(filename contains {"/", "\", ".", ":"})
    Canonicalize filename (INT 21H/AH=60H)
    If !(CF is set) filename is valid
Filename is not valid
```