# Why can I not  create files/folders with these names?

Tags: windows, filenames

Can anyone provides me details of why Windows does nto allow to create file/folders with below names?

- PRN
- AUX
- NUL
- LPT1
- COM1
- Potential drive letter - A: to Z:
- Other characters (such as `<`(less than), `>`(greater than), `:`(colon), `"`(double quote), `/`(forward slash), `\`(backslash), `|`(vertical bar or pipe), `?`(question mark), `*`(asterisk)

Comment: Check the answers to this post on StackOverflow.com: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62771/how-check-if-given-string-is-legal-allowed-file-name-under-windows

Comment: Nota bene: This likely only applies to file names as used by the *Windows API* as opposed to restrictions imposed by NTFS. You can create such files just fine when you're creating them in POSIX namespace – the file system couldn't care less.

Comment: You _can_ create `PRN`, `AUX`, and the rest: `\\.\C:\blah\nul`

Comment: Related: [Unable to rename a folder or a file as 'con'](https://superuser.com/q/86999/358766)

Answer (score 1):

Full details of what is allowed from MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(VS.85).aspx

> - Use a period to separate the base file name from the extension in the
>     name of a directory or file.
> - Use a backslash () to separate the components of a path. The backslash
>     divides the file name from the path to
>     it, and one directory name from
>     another directory name in a path. You
>     cannot use a backslash in the name for
>     the actual file or directory because
>     it is a reserved character that
>     separates the names into components.
> - Use a backslash as required as part of volume names, for example, the
>     "C:\" in "C:\path\file" or the
>     "\server\share" in
>     "\server\share\path\file" for
>     Universal Naming Convention (UNC)
>     names. For more information about UNC
>     names, see the Maximum Path Length
>     Limitation section.
> - Do not assume case sensitivity. For example, consider the names OSCAR,
>     Oscar, and oscar to be the same, even
>     though some file systems (such as a
>     POSIX-compliant file system) may
>     consider them as different. Note that
>     NTFS supports POSIX semantics for case
>     sensitivity but this is not the
>     default behavior. For more
>     information, see CreateFile.
> - Volume designators (drive letters) are similarly case-insensitive. For
>     example, "D:\" and "d:\" refer to the
>     same volume.
> - Use any character in the current code page for a name, including
>     Unicode characters and characters in
>     the extended character set (128–255),
>     except for the following:
>
>   - The following reserved characters:
>
>     - < (less than)
>     - > (greater than)
>     - : (colon)
>     - " (double quote)
>     - / (forward slash)
>     - \ (backslash)
>     - | (vertical bar or pipe)
>     - ? (question mark)
>     - * (asterisk)
>   - Integer value zero, sometimes referred to as the ASCII NUL
>       character.
>   - Characters whose integer representations are in the range from
>       1 through 31, except for alternate
>       streams where these characters are
>       allowed. For more information about
>       file streams, see File Streams.
>   - Any other character that the target file system does not allow.
> - Use a period as a directory component in a path to represent the
>     current directory, for example
>     ".\temp.txt". For more information,
>     see Paths.
> - Use two consecutive periods (..) as a directory component in a path to
>     represent the parent of the current
>     directory, for example "..\temp.txt".
>     For more information, see Paths.
> - Do not use the following reserved device names for the name of a file:
>
>   CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3,
>     COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9,
>     LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6,
>     LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9. Also avoid these
>     names followed immediately by an
>     extension; for example, NUL.txt is not
>     recommended. For more information, see
>     Namespaces.
> - Do not end a file or directory name with a space or a period. Although the
>     underlying file system may support
>     such names, the Windows shell and user
>     interface does not. However, it is
>     acceptable to specify a period as the
>     first character of a name. For
>     example, ".temp".

Answer (score 0):

> Also, neither a space nor a period can
>   be used at the end of a name. Further,
>   files cannot have the following
>   reserved device names: **CON, PRN, AUX,
>   NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5,
>   COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT1, LPT2,
>   LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8,
>   and LPT9**. Note that the case does not
>   matter in Windows.

There's more information you may find useful on the [page that came from *(Source)*](http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/filenames.htm).