# Why can't I create a folder named COM1

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to rename a folder or a file as 'con'](https://superuser.com/questions/86999/unable-to-rename-a-folder-or-a-file-as-con)

In linux it works, but not it Windows, I tried a lot and It just returns to "New Folder", why?

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/129141/creating-a-folder-named-con-in-windows, http://superuser.com/questions/338142/deleting-a-folder-named-con

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is a reserved keyword:

> Do not use the following reserved device names for the name of a file:
> CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9. Also avoid these names followed immediately by an extension; for example, NUL.txt is not recommended. For more information, see Namespaces.

[Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx)

### Additional Information

Raymond Chen also writes about these reserved names in his blog post [What's the deal with those reserved filenames like NUL and CON?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031022-00/?p=42073).

Long story short, they existed back in DOS 1.0 and are still around for compatibility reasons (no joke):

> #### But why do we carry these magic filenames forward even today?
>
> Because everybody still relies on them. Just look at all the batch files that do things like redirect to >NUL or test if a directory exists by asking "if exist directoryname\nul", or all the documentation that says to create a file with "copy CON ...".

Answer (score 3):

Com1 is the handle for serial port 1 on a pc (communication 1)

You may be able to do this from the command line by wrapping in quotes ( ren folder "com1"), but I'm unable to test right now.

Comment: No, adding quotes doesn't help. The name `com1` is reserved on the filesystem level, not at the parser level.

Answer (score 2):

You can't name folders/files `COM[1-9]` (there is more) because these are reserved as they are system communication ports.

A full list of reserved file/folder names can be found [here](http://www.computerfreetips.com/System_Tune-Up/reserved_words.html).