# Why can't you use special characters in a filename, like "?" or ";"?

Tags: windows, special-characters

When I try to save a file, if I use special characters in the name (such as a colon, question mark, or exclamation point) in Windows I get a message saying that the file name is invalid.

Why is that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040041/special-character-in-windows-file-name

Comment: In which program are you trying to save a file, and is the offending character in the file or (as it seems) in the filename?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words

Comment: Related: [Why can't I name a folder or file 'CON' in Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/86999/358766)

Answer (score 23):

There are several characters that have special meaning to Windows (and to DOS, where most of the characters originally came from)

from [MSDN](https://web.archive.org/web/20131128063632/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177506):

> A filename cannot contain any of the following characters:
> \ / : * ? " < > |

`/` is a switch (and also a directory separator).
`\` is a directory separator.
`:` is a drive designator.
`*` and `?` are wildcards used in searching.
`"` is a way to allow spaces in parameters.
`<` and `>` are redirection that allow input and output of a program to come from, and go to, something other than screen/keyboard.
`|` is a pipe that allows output from one program to be used as input to the next.

Comment: To clarify this answer, these special characters could interfere with parsing a command line (or path) if they were in a filename.  There is no requirement to delimit the filename in any way (e.g. surround it with quotes or spaces), so encountering such a special char would cause incorrect parsing (i.e is the special char part of the filename or an operator?).

Comment: It is, however, arguable that some of these restrictions are no longer necessary due to the handling of long filenames and quotations marks. ``\`` ``?`` ``*`` and ``"`` are the only ones really necessary in the current syntax, as the other characters are only useful outside of quotation marks. The exception is : which is only useful as the second character, which could be outlawed while allowing it elsewhere. In other words, no file named ``A:A letter's story.txt``, but no problem with a file named ``Sarah: My favorite cat.txt``

Comment: `<>"` are reserved wildcard characters. Windows uses them to implement the complex semantics for DOS `*?.` when translating to native NT, which has simple semantics for `*?.`. The six wildcard characters are reserved because Windows implements wildcard matching in the file system itself, i.e. directly in the `NtQueryDirectoryFile` system call, with no escaping mechanism. In Unix, wildcards are implemented at the application level, usually by a shell that supports escaping them.

Comment: Note that `:` is usually reserved in filenames, but not in file paths. It's used for device names and as the delimiter for file streams (e.g. "filename:streamname:streamtype"). Also, some file systems such as the VirtualBox shared-folder file system allow `:`, `|`, and ASCII control characters (1-31) in filenames, but they're reserved in all of Microsoft's file systems except for the named-pipe file system.