# Cannot create a specific file named “con.php” in Windows

Tags: windows-xp

I have Windows XP SP3 and cannot create the file named `con.php` anywhere on disk. I get a message that the file already exists.

Searching in Windows explorer I found not one such a file name on the whole disk.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Here is the brief discussion about restrictive file names in windows. `http://stackoverflow.com/a/3380159/866571`. Hope that may help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I name a folder or file 'CON' in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/86999/why-cant-i-name-a-folder-or-file-con-in-windows)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Con is a restricted filename in Windows, so you can't name any file or folder "con".  This link provides more info, as well as a utility that (apparently) lets you get around this restriction: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/create-restricted-files-folders-con-aux-nul-click-windows

Comment: Thanks Russianspi, but it's so stupid, isn't it? User should be given the message that the name is reserved, but not that the file already exists. Anyway, solved, thanks.

Comment: If it's any consolation, the error message in Windows 8 was something easily Googleable.